# Prevent "caching" in class method

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, caching

I have the following code:

```
public static string GetBlogPosts(string input)
        {
            var blogs = context.Blogs.OrderByDescending(a => a.Date).Take(3);

            string insertCode = "";

            foreach (var item in blogs)
            {
                insertCode += String.Format("<div class='blog-post'><h1>{0} <span class='blog-date sub'>({1}/{2})</span></h1>{3}</div>", 
                    item.Headline, item.Date.Day, item.Date.Month, item.Text);
            }

            // insert the code
            input = input.Replace("[widget=blogposts]", insertCode);

            return input;
        }
```

As you can probably see I use this method to replace the [widget=blogposts] with the actual code for showing the latest blog posts.

The only problem is that the result is cached, and doesn't change the result if I edit one of the blog posts.

Is there any way of turning off "caching" for a method in a class? Does somehow declaring the context as static caches the results and make them update only when the code compiles?

Edit! Here's all of the code in the class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using BandPage.Models;

namespace BandPage.Helpers
{
    public static class Widgets
    {
        public static BandPageContext context = new BandPageContext();

        public static string InsertWidgets(string input)
        {
            input = SocialMedia(input);
            input = GetBlogPosts(input);
            input = RecentBlogs(input);
            input = ContactForm(input);

            return input;
        }

        public static string SocialMedia(string input)
        {
            var socialMedia = context.SocialMedias.FirstOrDefault();

            string insertCode = "<div class='social-media'>";
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(socialMedia.Facebook))
            {
                insertCode += String.Format("<a href='{0}'><img src='/Images/icons/social-media/facebook.png' /></a>", socialMedia.Facebook); 
            }
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(socialMedia.Myspace))
            {
                insertCode += String.Format("<a href='{0}'><img src='/Images/icons/social-media/myspace.png' /></a>", socialMedia.Myspace);
            }
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(socialMedia.Soundcloud))
            {
                insertCode += String.Format("<a href='{0}'><img src='/Images/icons/social-media/soundcloud.png' /></a>", socialMedia.Soundcloud);
            }
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(socialMedia.Twitter))
            {
                insertCode += String.Format("<a href='{0}'><img src='/Images/icons/social-media/twitter.png' /></a>", socialMedia.Twitter);
            }
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(socialMedia.Instagram))
            {
                insertCode += String.Format("<a href='{0}'><img src='/Images/icons/social-media/instagram.png' /></a>", socialMedia.Instagram);
            }
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(socialMedia.GooglePlus))
            {
                insertCode += String.Format("<a href='{0}'><img src='/Images/icons/social-media/google_plus.png' /></a>", socialMedia.GooglePlus);
            }
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(socialMedia.Youtube))
            {
                insertCode += String.Format("<a href='{0}'><img src='/Images/icons/social-media/youtube.png' /></a>", socialMedia.Youtube);
            }
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(socialMedia.Spotify))
            {
                insertCode += String.Format("<a href='{0}'><img src='/Images/icons/social-media/spotify.png' /></a>", socialMedia.Spotify);
            }
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(socialMedia.Vimeo))
            {
                insertCode += String.Format("<a href='{0}'><img src='/Images/icons/social-media/vimeo.png' /></a>", socialMedia.Vimeo);
            }

            insertCode += "</div>";

            // insert the code
            input = input.Replace("[widget=socialmedia]", insertCode);

            return input;
        }



        public static string GetBlogPosts(string input)
        {
            var blogs = context.Blogs.OrderByDescending(a => a.Date).Take(3);

            string insertCode = "";

            foreach (var item in blogs)
            {
                insertCode += String.Format("<div class='blog-post'><h1>{0} <span class='blog-date sub'>({1}/{2})</span></h1>{3}</div>", 
                    item.Headline, item.Date.Day, item.Date.Month, item.Text);
            }

            // insert the code
            input = input.Replace("[widget=blogposts]", insertCode);

            return input;
        }

        public static string RecentBlogs(string input)
        {
            var blogs = context.Blogs.OrderByDescending(a => a.Date).Take(10);

            string insertCode = "<div class='blog-recent'>";

            foreach (var item in blogs)
            {
                insertCode += String.Format("<h4><a href='/blog/{0}'>{1} <span class='blog-date'>({2}/{3})</span></a></h4>", 
                    item.BlogId, item.Headline, item.Date.Day, item.Date.Month);
            }
            insertCode += "</div>";

            // insert the code
            input = input.Replace("[widget=recentblogs]", insertCode);

            return input;
        }

        public static string ContactForm(string input)
        {
            string insertCode =     @"<form id='contact-form'>
                                    <input type='text' name='email' id='email' placeholder='Your e-mail address' />
                                    <input type='text' name='subject' id='subject' placeholder='Subject' />

                                    <div class='cheater'>
                                        <input type='text' name='cheater' id='cheater' />
                                    </div>

                                    <textarea name='message' id='message' placeholder='Your message'></textarea>

                                    <label for='submit'></label>
                                    <input type='submit' name='submit' id='submit' value='Send' class='submit-button' />
                                    </form>

                                    <script src='/Scripts/ContactForm.js' type='text/javascript'></script>";

            // insert the code
            input = input.Replace("[widget=contactform]", insertCode);

            return input;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure its this method that's "caching" and not your browser itself? EDIT: Can you add debugging breakpoints and check that the method is entering when you expect it to and has the various values (say for `var blogs = context.Blogs...`) that you expect it to?

Comment: The string/results is definitely cached in some way. It's like it saves the results from the db call the first time. I've experienced this previously with helper methods, but instead of getting to the root of the problem, i've chosen another approach.

Answer (score 2):

All your methods (*SocialMedia,GetBlogPosts,RecentBlogs,ContactForm*) ends with

```
input = input.Replace("[widget=socialmedia]", insertCode);
return input;
```

How do you think this should work?

```
public static string InsertWidgets(string input)
{
    input = SocialMedia(input);
    input = GetBlogPosts(input);
    input = RecentBlogs(input);
    input = ContactForm(input);

    return input;
}
```

After the first method(SocialMedia) all `[widget=socialmedia]`s are replaced in the input string.

Comment: I don't really understand what you mean. I'm using the InsertWidgets like this:
@Html.Raw(InsertWidgets(Model.Text))
The first method (SocialMedia), takes the Model.Text and replaces [widget=socialmedia] with the code for social media buttons. The second method repaces [widget=blogposts] with the code for the blog posts. None of the other text gets affected, the functions just replace one text with another.

Comment: The methods are working like they should, the only problem is that the data fetched from the db gets cached as it were on the first request.

Comment: @MikaelEdebro Just after `input = SocialMedia(input);` in `InsertWidgets`, put a break point and see if `input` contains any more `[widget=socialmedia]`. You will not see any. Since all of its occurences is replaced in `SocialMedia`. So problem is not about caching. It is about your code.

Comment: @BTW: What I mean: The methods may work as they should, But they don't work well tohether in `InsertWidgets`

Comment: But why would I want any more [widget=socialmedia]? When the SocialMedia() has ran (thus replacing [widget=socialmedia] with the code for this), I want the following method to identify and replace another widget code. I don't think you understand my issue. How would this affect that the data gets cached? Like I said, the methods are working per se, in that they replace the [widget=xxxx] with the correct code. Only that they use old values from the db.

Comment: Lets say that I enter the page with the blog widget. Then I'll see the posts. If I then go and edit one of the posts in the db, and then refresh the page, the values are the same as the first request. And it's not browser caching.

Comment: @MikaelEdebro I don't get what is so hard to understand, What you simply do is `string s = "ABCD"; s = s.Replace("A", "123"); s = s.Replace("A", "456");`.

Comment: I also wonder why don'y you use the built-in nice debugger of Visual Studio. Put a breakpoint to `InsertWidgets` and watch step by step what is going on.

Comment: No that's not what I'm doing. I'm doing more like:
string s = "ABCD"; s = s.Replace("A", "123"); s = s.Replace("B", "456");
All the methods replaces a different widget code.

Comment: @MikaelEdebro OK, I quit, You do everything correct and you found a bug of .NET. We, poor souls, will continue to use the buggy version of it.

Comment: I understand that the issue lies in the code. Although you seem to be implying that there is something wrong with the replacing of the widget codes. That is working as it should. What I have been saying several times now is that the problem is that the method is displaying old db data. I'm wondering if it has anything to do with that the class and methods are static?

Answer (score 0):

I solved the "caching" issue with passing along the objects as a parameter to the methods. Not sure if this is considered bad coding structure, but at least it solved the problem with not getting the updated values.

I would appreciate it really much if anyone can shed some light over static and fetching data from a db. Is it supposed to work painlessly, or do declaring the context static somehow make it less prone to getting the latest values? I was thinking that it might have anything to do with something built in to .NET to improve performance?

```
 using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using BandPage.Models;

namespace BandPage.Helpers
{
    public static class Widgets
    {
        public static string InsertWidgets(string input)
        {
            BandPageContext context = new BandPageContext();
            input = SocialMedia(input, context.SocialMedias.FirstOrDefault());
            input = GetBlogPosts(input, context.Blogs.OrderByDescending(a => a.Date).Take(3));
            input = RecentBlogs(input, context.Blogs.OrderByDescending(a => a.Date).Take(10));
            input = ContactForm(input);

            return input;
        }

        public static string SocialMedia(string input, SocialMedia socialMedia)
        {
            string insertCode = "<div class='social-media'>";
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(socialMedia.Facebook))
            {
                insertCode += String.Format("<a href='{0}'><img src='/Images/icons/social-media/facebook.png' /></a>", socialMedia.Facebook); 
            }
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(socialMedia.Myspace))
            {
                insertCode += String.Format("<a href='{0}'><img src='/Images/icons/social-media/myspace.png' /></a>", socialMedia.Myspace);
            }
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(socialMedia.Soundcloud))
            {
                insertCode += String.Format("<a href='{0}'><img src='/Images/icons/social-media/soundcloud.png' /></a>", socialMedia.Soundcloud);
            }
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(socialMedia.Twitter))
            {
                insertCode += String.Format("<a href='{0}'><img src='/Images/icons/social-media/twitter.png' /></a>", socialMedia.Twitter);
            }
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(socialMedia.Instagram))
            {
                insertCode += String.Format("<a href='{0}'><img src='/Images/icons/social-media/instagram.png' /></a>", socialMedia.Instagram);
            }
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(socialMedia.GooglePlus))
            {
                insertCode += String.Format("<a href='{0}'><img src='/Images/icons/social-media/google_plus.png' /></a>", socialMedia.GooglePlus);
            }
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(socialMedia.Youtube))
            {
                insertCode += String.Format("<a href='{0}'><img src='/Images/icons/social-media/youtube.png' /></a>", socialMedia.Youtube);
            }
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(socialMedia.Spotify))
            {
                insertCode += String.Format("<a href='{0}'><img src='/Images/icons/social-media/spotify.png' /></a>", socialMedia.Spotify);
            }
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(socialMedia.Vimeo))
            {
                insertCode += String.Format("<a href='{0}'><img src='/Images/icons/social-media/vimeo.png' /></a>", socialMedia.Vimeo);
            }

            insertCode += "</div>";

            // insert the code
            input = input.Replace("[widget=socialmedia]", insertCode);

            return input;
        }



        public static string GetBlogPosts(string input, IEnumerable<Blog> blogs)
        {
            string insertCode = "";

            foreach (var item in blogs)
            {
                insertCode += String.Format("<div class='blog-post'><h1>{0} <span class='blog-date sub'>({1}/{2})</span></h1>{3}</div>", 
                    item.Headline, item.Date.Day, item.Date.Month, item.Text);
            }

            // insert the code
            input = input.Replace("[widget=blogposts]", insertCode);

            return input;
        }

        public static string RecentBlogs(string input, IEnumerable<Blog> blogs)
        {
            string insertCode = "<div class='blog-recent'>";

            foreach (var item in blogs)
            {
                insertCode += String.Format("<h4><a href='/blog/{0}'>{1} <span class='blog-date'>({2}/{3})</span></a></h4>", 
                    item.BlogId, item.Headline, item.Date.Day, item.Date.Month);
            }
            insertCode += "</div>";

            // insert the code
            input = input.Replace("[widget=recentblogs]", insertCode);

            return input;
        }

        public static string ContactForm(string input)
        {
            string insertCode =     @"<form id='contact-form'>
                                    <input type='text' name='email' id='email' placeholder='Your e-mail address' />
                                    <input type='text' name='subject' id='subject' placeholder='Subject' />

                                    <div class='cheater'>
                                        <input type='text' name='cheater' id='cheater' />
                                    </div>

                                    <textarea name='message' id='message' placeholder='Your message'></textarea>

                                    <label for='submit'></label>
                                    <input type='submit' name='submit' id='submit' value='Send' class='submit-button' />
                                    </form>

                                    <script src='/Scripts/ContactForm.js' type='text/javascript'></script>";

            // insert the code
            input = input.Replace("[widget=contactform]", insertCode);

            return input;
        }
    }
}
```